# JS method and closure

Tags: javascript, methods, closures

Does closure apply to object's methods in JS? I am new to JS. In the following code I deduce that objects do not create scope  and methods remember their lexical environment, even though they are defined as property on object.

```
let name = "doe";
function foo() {
    let name = "jane";
    return {
        name: "jonh",
        sayName() {
            console.log(name);
        },
    };
}

foo().sayName(); // jane
```

Comment: If you want name to be "jonh" then you should use `this.name` which will refer to the returned object from `foo`. Otherwise you get "jane" because the binding "name" in `sayName` closes over the variable from `foo`'s scope.

Comment: I sort of guessed that's the rule, but wasn't quite sure. Thank you for confirming my intuition.